# Can't install SDWebImage with CocoaPods : "ld: library not found for -lSDWebImage"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I'm trying to import SDWebImage into my iOS project using Cocoapods.

So I have installed Cocoapods, and created this Podfile into my project directory :

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
target 'MyProjectV6' do
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
end
```

Then I run it with the `pod install` command, and everything seems to be fine :

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing SDWebImage 3.7.5 (was 3.7.5)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

I also see in Xcode a `Pods` folder created into my project directory. It contains two `.xcconfig` files like this :

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SDWebImage"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SDWebImage"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"SDWebImage" -framework "ImageIO"
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

But when I build my project, I get this error :

[image]

I also have a "libPods-MyProjectV6.a" added into my Frameworks folder, but the text is red, so I guess something is wrong but I don't know what...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you open Workspace or Project file?
Verify that you open first one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock
pod install
```

Comment: Yes I did, I just forgot to open my Workspace instead of my Project file. Thanks anyway.